# Lock-free, constant update-time concurrent tree data-structures?

Tags: reference-request, ds.data-structures, time-complexity, tree, concurrency

I've been reading a bit of the literature lately, and have found some rather interesting data-structures.

I have researched various different methods of getting update times down to $\mathcal{O}(1)$ worst-case update time [1-7].

Recently I begun looking into lock-free data-structures, to support efficient concurrent access.

**Have any of these worst-case $\mathcal{O}(1)$ update-time techniques been used in the implementation of lock-free data structures?**

I ask because; to me, they seem like the obvious practical extension of this "theoretical enhancement".

---

1. [Tarjan, Robert Endre. “Updating a Balanced Search Tree in O(1) Rotations.” Information Processing Letters 16, no. 5 (1983): 253 – 257.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019083900996)
2. [Driscoll, J R, N Sarnak, D D Sleator, and R E Tarjan. “Making Data Structures Persistent.” In Proceedings of the Eighteenth Annual ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing, 109–121. STOC  ’86. New York, NY, USA: ACM, 1986.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.133.4630)
3. [Levcopoulos, C., and Mark H. Overmars. “A Balanced Search Tree with O(1) Worst Case Update Time.” Acta Inf. 26, no. 3 (November 1988): 269–277.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00299635)
4. [Fleischer, Rudolf. A Simple Balanced Search Tree With O(1) Worst-Case Update Time](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.9433)
5. [Dietz, Paul F, and Rajeev Raman. “A Constant Update Time Finger Search Tree.” Information Processing Letters 52, no. 3 (1994): 147 – 154.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190%2894%2900115-4)
6. [Lagogiannis, George, Christos Makris, Yannis Panagis, Spyros Sioutas, and Kostas Tsichlas. “New Dynamic Balanced Search Trees with Worst-case Constant Update Time.” J. Autom. Lang. Comb. 8, no. 4 (July 2003): 607–632.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=998223.998229)
7. [Brodal, Gerth Stølting, George Lagogiannis, Christos Makris, Athanasios Tsakalidis, and Kostas Tsichlas. “Optimal Finger Search Trees in the Pointer Machine.” J. Comput. Syst. Sci. 67, no. 2 (September 2003): 381–418.](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/stoc02.pdf)

FYI: This is a reposting of [Lock-free, constant update-time concurrent tree data-structures?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2680)

Comment: [Crossposted on cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2680/98).

Comment: @Raphael: I mentioned on that question and in this question that it had been crossposted. JeffE recommended I crosspost.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the remark at the end.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "lock free"? it is possible for a datastructure to minimize locking by locking subelements instead of the entire datastructure.